# Is it possible to programmatically add an image file to an image or commandbutton control in a vba userform?

Tags: excel, vba, image, userform

I am trying to get a image to load programmatically into image and commandbutton MSForms controls to no avail without the VB editor. I am using the macro structure below which works well with other controls. Microsoft indicates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.commandbutton.picture) that the editor must be used:

> You must use the control's property page to assign a bitmap to the
> Picture property. You cannot use the Visual Basic LoadPicture function
> to assign a bitmap to Picture.

The macro below works when the `.Picture` command is commented out without image of course. When loading an image into a commandbutton the same problem occurs. I have tried various ways to provide the file location but it always errors out. Does someone know a clever work around?

```
Sub NewForm()

Dim TempForm As Object
Dim NewImage As MSForms.Image

Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
With TempForm
 .Properties("Height") = 300
 .Properties("Width") = 300
End With

Set NewImage = TempForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.image.1")
With NewImage
 .Picture = "C:\image.jpg"  'Nothing works here it seems
 .Height = 100
 .Left = 100
 .Top = 100
 .Width = 100
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This works. I just tested it.... `.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\image.jpg")` The two changes that I made: **1.** I changed `Dim NewImage As MSForms.Image` to `Dim NewImage As Object` **2.** I used an image from my pc.

Comment: Siddharth, you rock! Works like a charm

Comment: I already posted an answer showing how it works for both image and command button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example to add Images to Image and Command Button.

Three changes that I made

1. I changed `Dim NewImage As MSForms.Image` to `Dim NewImage As Object`. Using `Dim NewImage As Image` will also work.
2. I used an image from my pc.
3. I used `LoadPicture()`.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewForm()
    Dim TempForm As Object
    Dim NewImage As Object

    Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
    With TempForm
        .Properties("Height") = 300
        .Properties("Width") = 300
    End With
    
    '~~> Image Control
    Set NewImage = TempForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.image.1")
    With NewImage
        .Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Start.Bmp")
        .Height = 100
        .Left = 100
        .Top = 10
        .Width = 100
    End With
    
    '~~> Command Button
    Dim ctl_Command As Control
    Set ctl_Command = TempForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CmdXYZ", False)
    
    With ctl_Command
        .Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Start.Bmp")
        .Left = 100
        .Top = 140
        .Height = 50
        .Width = 50
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Yes that what I needed. Since I am loading the properties from a cell, I am using: `.Picture = LoadPicture(Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("H10").Value)` which also works as intended. Thanks, that helped!