# Display image in UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, image, userform

While trying to display an image in a UserForm I get this message:

> '438' object doesn't support this property or method image control

In the first textbox (img_path) I input the path to the image's directory.
In the second one I input the file's name (NameImg).
Both textboxes' values are combined into path to the image for image control (ImgControl).

```vb
Private Sub Show_Click()
    Dim show_img As String
    Dim img As String
    ing = NameImg.Value + ".jpg"

    show_img = img_path.Text + img
    ImgControl = LoadPicture(show_img)
End Sub

Private Sub Select_Click()
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim path As String
    
    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Title = "Select a Directory"
    
    If diaFolder.Show = -1 Then
        path = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
        path = path + "\"
        img_path.Text = path
    End If
    
    Set diaFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

The path to the jpg file is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74664316/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-add-an-image-file-to-an-image-or-commandbutto

Comment: `ImgControl.Picture = LoadPicture(show_img)`  Also note typo `ing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tim Williams pointed out I forgot about Picture property here:
`ImgControl = LoadPicture(show_img)`
it should be

```
ImgControl.Picture = LoadPicture(show_img)
```